# How to output client console.log in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am using CasperJS to capture the log of browser console, but it does not work.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  logLevel: "debug"
});

var domain, port, userName, designID, token, outPath, reportUrl, explorerUrl, sourcePage;
var images = [];

if(casper.cli.has(5)){
  // Get argvs
  domain = casper.cli.get(0).toLowerCase();
  port = casper.cli.get(1);
  userName = casper.cli.get(2);
  designID = casper.cli.get(3);
  token = casper.cli.get(4);
  outPath = casper.cli.get(5);
}

reportUrl = 'http://' + domain + ':' + port + '/design?file_id=' + designID;

casper.on('remote.message', function(message) {
  this.log('remote message caught: ' + message);
});

casper.start(reportUrl, function() {
  this.evaluate(function sendLog(log) {
    // you can access the log from page DOM
    console.log('from the browser, I can tell you there are ' + 
    log.length + ' entries in the log');
  }, this.result.log);
});

casper.run();
```

In Chrome, the page will output some log like:

```
get userdata
get designdata
Success!
```

But in CasperJS, it does not output any log.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace `log` with `echo`, you should see that the following (simplified) script is working:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.on('remote.message', function (message) {
  this.echo('Message: ' + message);
});

casper.start('http://example.com/');

casper.waitForSelector('body', function () {
  this.evaluate(function () {
    console.log('Hello, World!');
  });
});

casper.run();
```

But if you really want to use `log`, you need to specify the `verbose` option along with the log level...

**From the command line:**

```
casperjs --log-level=debug --verbose=true example.js
```

**From the script:**

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  logLevel: 'debug',
  verbose: true
});
```